# check duplicate rand function value in database and generate it again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i create rand funtion for generating random value and concatenate with other value and show in the text field through ajax before insert this value. but here how can i check this random generating value is exists or not in database before inserting this value in database.if value is exists then again generate rand function value and again concatenate this and show the value in textbox. how can i do this? my code is below 
    index.php

```
    <html>    
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {});
    function my_validate_func() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var year = $('#year').val();
    var course = $('#course').val();
    var branch_name = $('#branch_name').val();
        if ($('#name').val() != "" && $('#year').val() != "" &&
            $('#course').val() != "" && $('#branch_name').val() != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'roll.php',
                data: { name: name, year: year, branch_name: branch_name, course: course },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#roll').val(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onChange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" onChange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="course" id="course" onChange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="center" id="center" onChange="my_validate_func()">
        <input type="text" name="roll" id="roll" value="">
    </form>
</body>

</html>

roll.php





    <?php
function calculateRoll()
{
    $name1        = $_POST['name'];
    $year1        = $_POST['year'];
    $course1      = $_POST['course'];
    $branch_name1 = $_POST['branch_name'];
    $name2        = substr($name1,0,3);
    $name         = strtoupper($name2);
    $year         = substr($year1,-2);
    $branch_name  = strtoupper(substr($branch_name1,0,3));
    $course2      = substr($course1,0,3);
    $course       = strtoupper($course2);
    $rand         = rand(100000,999999);
    $roll         =$branch_name.$name.$course.$year.$rand;
    //return $roll;
    echo $roll;
}

function isValidRoll($roll) {
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("sigma");
    $sql="SELECT count(*) as total FROM student WHERE roll = '$roll'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $data['total'] == 0;
}

$validRoll = false;
$roll = calculateRoll();
while (!$validRoll) {
    if (isValidRoll($roll)) {
        $validRoll = true;
    } else {
        $roll = calculateRoll();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: post the full code. this does not help

Comment: You can make the field in the database unique. So when you're trying to do the insert, you'll get an error and you'll know that field already exists OR just select the rows if you already got them.

Comment: You check by using `SELECT...WHERE columnName = rand`. If it returned a result, it means there is a duplicate, if not, then it does not exist yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use md5 function and/or time() function such as:

```
$rand         = md5(time() + rand(100000,999999));
```

Your updated code should be:

```
$name1        = $_POST['name'];
$year1        = $_POST['year'];
$course1      = $_POST['course'];
$branch_name1 = $_POST['branch_name'];
$name2        = substr($name1,0,3);
$name         = strtoupper($name2);
$year         = substr($year1,-2);
$branch_name  = strtoupper(substr($branch_name1,0,3));
$course2      = substr($course1,0,3);
$course       = strtoupper($course2);
$rand         = md5(time() + rand(100000,999999));
$roll         = $branch_name.$name.$course.$year.$rand;

echo $roll;
```

This solution provide unique value. You can use also `uniqid()` function. Also remember to set as unique the database field.

---

Another solution is to keep roll creation login in a function and create another function to check if the roll exists or not. Your responsibility to check if other rolls are store in the db or in a text file, ...

```
function calculateRoll()
{
    $name1        = $_POST['name'];
    $year1        = $_POST['year'];
    $course1      = $_POST['course'];
    $branch_name1 = $_POST['branch_name'];
    $name2        = substr($name1,0,3);
    $name         = strtoupper($name2);
    $year         = substr($year1,-2);
    $branch_name  = strtoupper(substr($branch_name1,0,3));
    $course2      = substr($course1,0,3);
    $course       = strtoupper($course2);
    $rand         = rand(100000,999999);
    return $branch_name.$name.$course.$year.$rand;
}

function isValidRoll($roll) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total FROM student WHERE roll = '$roll'")
        or die("Query not valid: " . mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $data['total'] == 0;
}

$validRoll = false;
$roll = calculateRoll();
while (!$validRoll) {
    if (isValidRoll($roll)) {
        $validRoll = true;
    } else {
        $roll = calculateRoll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this does not answer OP's question, it does provide a good alternative

Comment: Instead of solve problem, sometimes is better avoid them ^_^

Comment: ok if i use md5 function then roll number is very long value. i want to show like that MUMSUSII88987654

Comment: Yes, I am updating my answer. You can split logic of creation of the roll and create a function to check the uniqueness. Then, ... generate rolls until the roll create is unique.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? I mean, ... what's wrong with `$branch_name.$name.$course.$year.$rand`?

Comment: IN your code section function isValidRoll($roll) {
    // ...
} what can i write here, can i type here code for fetching data from mysql database?

Comment: I dont know where other roll are stored. I can make a check if I do not know where I have to check XD

Comment: "student" table. in "roll" field in mysql database

Comment: select count(id) from student where roll = '$roll'; ... ?

Comment: if roll exists then return value 1 if not then return 0 .then ? but how can i implement in your code?

Comment: Just try it! Before asking, ... try ^_^

Comment: NOT GENERATE ROLL. WAIT I UPDATE roll.php code check it

Comment: code is ok, but why roll is not generate? i can not understand.

Comment: because I forgot return statement in the function that generates the roll. I've update my code

Comment: Still not generate :(

Comment: Ok, ... move php code before the form and update form with `<input type="text" name="roll" id="roll" value="<?php echo $roll; ?>">`

Comment: I think is there any problem? return $branch_name.$name.$course.$year.$rand; so could not print roll ?

Comment: function isValidRoll($roll) {
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("sigma");
 $sql="SELECT count(*) as total FROM student WHERE roll = '$roll'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
        
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $data['total'] == 0;
}

$validRoll = false;
$roll = calculateRoll();
while (!$validRoll) {
    if (isValidRoll($roll)) {
        $validRoll = true;
    } else {
        $roll = calculateRoll();
    }
} is there any problem? parenthesis or other?

Comment: now generate, i update your code just one line check is it ok or not?

Comment: now generate, i update your code just one line,and update my code check is it ok or not? in this way to create unique roll number is possible or not from your code?please check my code

Comment: yes working.. but i want to know is there any possibility to generate duplicate value? because i check my database and my database is small ,very small amount of data here, so not generate duplicate value till now, but when i put this code in  large database where large amount of data created then  is there any possibility for generate duplicate value?

Comment: If you want to generate unique id use this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Here also does not guarantee 100% to generate unique Id :),

Comment: Is not your problem: if a duplicate is generated, ... just recreate another. Your question here was to make this check. I got a response. I've spent my time for you. Please accept my response and start asking others. You cant ask thousands question in same time ^_^. Ok?

Answer (score 1):

when ever you save the data of the form store rand function value too means in second time you can retrieve the rand function value and compare with current rand function generating value.